# Xcode Breakpoint opening in debug mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've breakpoint in my code and when code reaches the breakpoint, instead of regular code view, Xcode moves to debug mode. How to turn off the debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, Here is how to disable the debug mode. Uncheck the "Always Show Disassembly" under "Debug Workflow".
[image]